# How can I use jQuery to show and fade out an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a simple button that displays a number when clicked. The number then fades out after 5 seconds and disappears.

I am having trouble with the jQuery.

Please see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/)

Code here:

```
$(".vote-number").hide();

$("vote-btn").click(function(){
    $(".vote-number").show();
}, function(){
    $(".vote-number").hide();
}).click(function() {
    $(".vote-number").show().fadeOut(5000);
});
```

Comment: click method only accept one handler, here only the second one is fired  http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/2/  indeed, you just need: `$(".vote-btn").click(function(){
    $(".vote-number").show().fadeOut(5000);
});`

Comment: And see using .finish() method for better user experience if link clicked many times in a row: http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/5/

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. How would I specify each element. If I duplicate the buttons and answers and press the button it loads up all the numbers. see fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/10/

Comment: This is not valid HTML, DIV cannot be direct child of an UL, only LI even in your jsfiddle you forgot to post the UL markup but: http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/11/  (i see my jsfiddle in first comment was not valid too nor this one... so my apologies!)

Comment: no worries. here is updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/12/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/12/

Answer (score 1):

Typo

It should be

```
$(".vote-btn").click(function(){ // you missed [dot]
```

Use `setTimeout()` method to fade div.
Write:

```
$(".vote-number").hide();
$(".vote-btn").click(function () {
    $(".vote-number").show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".vote-number").fadeOut();
    }, 5000);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/6/)

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. How would I specify each element. If I duplicate the buttons and answers and press the button it loads up all the numbers. see fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/10/

Comment: @user2965875 your HTML markup is not valid. I would do it [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/21/). [working demo with your markup here.](http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/23/)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix with just change `$("vote-btn")` with `$(".vote-btn")` because vote-btn is the class name and not the element name.

[updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/4/)

code:

```
$(".vote-number").hide();

$(".vote-btn").click(function(){
   $(".vote-number").show();
}, function(){
   $(".vote-number").hide();
}).click(function() {
   $(".vote-number").show().fadeOut(5000);
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. How would I specify each element. If I duplicate the buttons and answers and press the button it loads up all the numbers. see fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/10/